# Simple python request to update GitHub file

Tags: python, api, github, python-requests, github-api

I haven't seen many good resources on this topic, but from what I found I managed to make this script to update a simple text file to have just a 1:

```
payload = {
  "message": "update file.txt",
  "committer": {
    "name": "<name>",
    "email": "<email>"
  },
  "content": "1",
  "sha": "<sha>"
}

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo>/contents/file.txt"
token = '<token>'
usern = '<username>'

rget = requests.get(url)
print(rget)

rput = requests.put(url, auth=(usern, token), data=json.dumps(payload))
print(rput)
```

The get request works but the put requests gives a 422 error. Any idea how I can fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem: Needed to encode the message. Used this:

```
message = "1"
message_bytes = message.encode("ascii")
content = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
```